# Backendless : Relationship between tables issue and advice

Tags: javascript, database, api, rest

Good evening,

I currently have 3 tables on my API at backendless.

**Users** (objectId, email, username, password)

**figures** (objectId, figure_name, figure_cat, figure_image, figure_info)

My figures data has rows kind of like a product.

Basically, I would like to link entries in the figures table to users but i'm not sure the best way to go about it.

I can create relationships of one-to-one and one-to-many but being new to that i'm not sure the best way to go about it.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

does a user have many figures? 
Can multiple users share the same Figure?

Assuming that a user has many figures, so you will have a userid column in the figures table (1:M rel between user->figures). I also assume your figure_cat is a relatively static list, so consider a lookup table for that so it has a fkey in the figures table as well. Also depending on the size of images, it may be better to put images in a different table so you can put them in a different file group.

Assuming figures are shared by users, you may need a M:N table in between users and figures that stores the userid, to figureid mapping (sometimes called a "tie table" I think)

What database are you using?

Comment: Hi @markg - Thanks for the reply. So basically what i would like is the user will view a list of figures and then i would like them to be able to mark they have that figure.

In the past (on MySQL) i would have done a junction table with the users ID and the id of the figure but it' proving hard with using Backendless.com and there REST api.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relationship between the tables either directly in the console or by making an API call where you save an object which references other (related) objects. See the documentation for details: http://backendless.com/documentation/data/js/data_relations.htm